# Different image representation and how do paper usually calculate evaluation metrics

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have a question about the evaluation of prediction results on the KITTI image. I used a model provided from [Monocular depth estimation](https://github.com/compphoto/BoostingMonocularDepth) and observe the result using the code below

```
depth_gt = Image.open(path)
depth_gt = np.asarray(depth_gt, dtype=np.float32)
print(depth_gt)
```

I observe that the "pixel" value of the image is of range [0, 65535], but doing the same to the ground truth image returns a range of [0, 255]. Opening the image using just `cv2.imread()` on the other hand returns both the ground truth and the image to be within the range of [0, 255]. Why are there such differences? If I were to perform evaluation matrices on them which one do I use and should I perform any normalization/re-scaling?

Images for the RGB, ground truth, and prediction are below. The exact pixel intensity of the ground truth for this image is actually between [6, 24] and the prediction result is between [0, 255] if the image were opened using `cv2.imread()`
[image: RGB]
[image: Ground Truth]
[image: Prediction]

My main objective is to calculate metrics such as RMSE, ordinal error, and δ1.25 for a testing dataset of ~700 images. Any advice or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Edit: [image: table5]

I found another evaluation metric that evaluates the relative depth similar to the ordinal error, WHDR, and the paper that introduces the WHDR metric is from [Intrinsic Images in the Wild](http://opensurfaces.cs.cornell.edu/publications/intrinsic/) but a human judgment JSON file is required using the code provided. I would like to compute the WHDR metric using the ground truth depth map and the prediction depth map, like those datasets shown in the table image above. Any clue or suggestions will help greatly! Thanks again!

Table image is from the paper [Learning to Recover 3D Scene Shape from a Single Image](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.09365.pdf)

Comment: ground truth is probably in meters, and floating point.

Comment: Thanks for the input, in this case, should I calculate the evaluation metrics using the meter's value (using PIL) or the greyscale image value with scale = [0, 255] (cv2)? And should I do a normalization before comparing it with the ground truth?